# restrict space at first position in textbox using Angular 6

Tags: html, regex, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a situation where I need to restrict users from entering space in the beginning of a TextBox. I am able to restrict space entry in TextBox. But not having any clues about not allowing at first position.

I am looking for a solution using Angular 6. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking for a regex - `^(?!\s+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve it with Vanilla JavaScript.

1) The use of [string.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with Regex.

Explanation: `^` matches the starting position (leading),`\s` matches a white-space character, and `+` matches the subsequent elements.  When you use them together, `^\s+` will match 1 or more leading spaces.

```js
const originalString = '      my Name is WenTjun';
const result = originalString.replace(/^\s+/g, '');
console.log(originalString);
console.log(result);
```

2) The use of [String.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim). Do note that this trims both leading and trailing spaces, hence you might not want to use this if you wish to preserve the trailing spaces.

```js
const originalString = '      my Name is WenTjun';
const result = originalString.trim();
console.log(originalString);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" (click)="handleInput($event)">
```

TS

```
handleInput(event) {
    if (event.which === 32 && !this.value.length)
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

This will not allow user to add space at first place only

Comment: `var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
{ if (k == 32) return false;}`
It'll allow user to not add space at any place.

Comment: @amrendra that is why I am checking `length`

Answer (score 0):

<input type="text" (keydown)="space($event)" name="name"/>

// TS File

public space(event:any){

```
if (event.target.selectionStart === 0 && event.code === 'Space'){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).